# how do i add a specific and constant tickerid into pinescript to use as a secondary entry condition?

Tags: pine-script, cryptocurrency

I have an existing v4 pinescript script that creates a buy alert for use in the crypto market.  the script refers to the chart tickerid.  i want to add an additional condition whereby the script looks at the RSI of another tickerid (a common market cap ticker such as tradingview - "TOTAL").

i need assistance in adding the secondary ticker into the script.  thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the request.security function: [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request{dot}security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity)

```
sec = request.security("TOTAL", timeframe.period, my_rsi)
```

Comment: thanks mate sorry for the late reply.  so version 4 is just security....not request.security?  also whats the my_rsi referencing?

Comment: rsiLookback = input(title="RSI Lookback",type=input.integer, defval=14)
rsiBase = input(title="RSI Base",type=input.integer,defval=50)
rsi = rsi(close,rsiLookback)
sec = security("TOTAL", timeframe.period, rsiBase)
rsiLong = (rsi,sec) < (rsi,close)

Comment: sorry i made a mess :(